# If an object is not null use it's value, otherwise use a default value to check an input checkbox in thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm using an object that may be null in a form to decide if an input checkebox must be ckecked or not. If the object (paramDTO) is not null, i want use its inner attribute (boolean check) to set it's value. If the object is null, i want that the checkbox be checked as default. How to do that?

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{/param}" th:object="${paramDTO}" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" th:checked="${paramDTO?.check}" checked />
</form>
```